# Writing $\sqrt[\large3]2+\sqrt[\large3]4$ with nested roots

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

Let $C\subset\Bbb R$ be the smallest set containing $0$ and closed under whole number addition/subtraction, whole number exponents, and whole number roots. That is, for all $c\in C$ and $n\in\Bbb N$, we have $c\pm n\in C$, $c^n\in C$, and $c^{1/n}\in C$.

We know that $\sqrt2+\sqrt3\in C$, since it's equal to $\sqrt{\sqrt{24}+5}$. Similarly, Ramanujan proved that:
$$\sqrt[\large3]{\sqrt[\large3]{1458}-9}-1=\sqrt[\large3]4-\sqrt[\large3]2$$
so $\sqrt[\large3]4-\sqrt[\large3]2\in C$. (Well, Ramanujan proved something equivalent.)

I found that $\left(\sqrt[\large3]2-1\right)^{-1}-1=\sqrt[\large3]2+\sqrt[\large3]4$, but I'm not allowed to use negative exponents/roots, so this doesn't prove that $\sqrt[\large3]2+\sqrt[\large3]4\in C$. So:

> Is it true that $\sqrt[\large3]2+\sqrt[\large3]4\in C$? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sqrt[\large3]2+\sqrt[\large3]4$ is indeed in $C$:
$$\sqrt{(\sqrt[\large3]{2} + 1)^2+3}=\sqrt[\large3]2+\sqrt[\large3]4$$

First, let's think about the process the other way around, instead of starting at $0$ and working our way to the number, start at the number and get to a whole number. Our goal is to get an expression with only one [surd](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Surd_(mathematics)&redirect=no). After some messing around you realize that just addition and exponentiation isn't cutting it like it did for the other examples, so we must take a root. For convenience let $x=\sqrt[\large3]2$, and observe that $ax^2 + bx + c$ can represent every result of the operations allowed. So if we can get to a quadratic with an integer single root, we found a way to get rid off one of the surds.

$$(x^2+x)^2=x^4+2x^3+x^2=2x+4+x^2=x^2+2x+1+3=(x+1)^2+3$$
$$x^2+x=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+3}$$

$\sqrt[\large3]{6+\sqrt{(\sqrt[\large3]{864}+3)^2+135}}$ was the original solution, based on the quadratic ($x^2 + x +\frac{1}{4}$) my friend suggested (He came up with the idea of thinking about it as a quadratic with a single root). By the way, we can use the same method to get another identity:
$$\sqrt{(\sqrt[\large3]{2} + 1)^2-5}=\sqrt[\large3]4-\sqrt[\large3]2$$

My follow-up questions are:

1. $\sqrt[\large3]2+\sqrt[\large3]4$ can be expressed in similar way but without whole number exponentiation?
2. Is $\sqrt[\large3]2+\sqrt[\large3]3$ in $C$? Is $\sqrt2+\sqrt[\large3]3$ in $C$?

Comment: Wow! Thank you! May I ask how you found this question (since it was written over a year ago)?

Comment: [From here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987168/does-this-trigonometric-pattern-continue-for-all-primes-p-6m1) (intresteing question) and through some of related questions links, I think.

Comment: Hello again! See Quanto's answer.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2):

Note
$$(\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4 -1)^2= 5- \sqrt[3]{4}
$$
which yields
$$\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4 =\sqrt{5-\sqrt[3]{4}}+1$$

Comment: Wow! Well done! I'm also impressed that you managed to find this question, which is five years old now.

Comment: I think technically it should be $\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{-4}+5}+1$ to be "legal" (no need to edit though)

Comment: @Akiva Weinberger - okay, I won’t bother changing it